# Transform directory to object in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to parse some files this way:

```
File(tentConfig.getPathRepository())
            .walkTopDown()
            .forEach { file -> processFile(file) }
```

the path of this file is: `/communications/email/begginer/.file`

I have to convert that path to object like this:
my **communications** should be my category, **email** should be a subcategory of communications and **beginner** subcategory of email.

my process method is responsible to serialize this path to object but I'm pretty sure there is a better solution.

```
private fun processCategory(currentFile: File) {
    val listOfDirectory = currentFile.path.split("/".toRegex())

    listOfDirectory.forEachIndexed { index, folderName ->
        if (index == 0) {
            val currentCategory = parseYmlFile(currentFile, Category::class)
            lesson.categories.forEach { itCategory ->
                if (itCategory.title != currentCategory.title) lesson.categories.add(currentCategory)
            }

        } else {
            val subCategory = parseYmlFile(currentFile, Category::class)
            lesson.categories[subCategory.index].subcategories.add(subCategory)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem? what is your solution missing?

Comment: @ESalaIt does not convert my subcategory correctly of email for communications and beginner for email

Comment: Are your paths always going to contain 1 folder and 2 sub-folders?

Comment: @NSimon nope, It should be N folder into the main folder like AA/B/CC/F convert this form  Category(AA).addSubCategory(B).addsubCategory(CC).addSubCategory(F)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of demo/testing purposes, my implementation of Category might be different from yours. Here's the one I was using:

```
inner class Category(val s: String, var subCategory: Category? = null)
```

Now that being said, here's a little function that will loop through the path of the given File, and construct a Category hierarchy, placing each element in the right order:

```
private fun processCategory(currentFile: File): Category? {
        val listOfDirectory = currentFile.path.split("/".toRegex())

        //The root category (in your example, communications)
        var rootCategory: Category? = null
        //A reminder of the current Category, so we can attach the next one to it
        var currentCategory: Category? = null
        listOfDirectory.forEach {
            if (rootCategory == null) {
                //First element, so I need to create the root category
                rootCategory = Category(it)
                currentCategory = rootCategory
            } else {
                //Other elements are simply created
                val nextCategory = Category(it)
                //Added as a subCategory of the previous category
                currentCategory!!.subCategory = nextCategory
                //And we progress within the chain
                currentCategory = nextCategory
            }
        }
        //In the end, my root category will contain :
        // Category("communications", Category("email", Category("Beginner", null)))
        return rootCategory
    }
```

You can surely adapt this code to your needs, by replacing the constructor that I'm using with your YmlParser